# How to get an EV signed dll to load on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, driver, signing

We recently started EV-signing our drivers and Windows authentication packages (what a headache that is).  The EV-signed build that we're now producing now works on Windows 10 with device guard etc.  However, I'm finding that our LSA package (which is EV signed with an SHA-256 digest) can no longer be loaded on Windows 7, even though the Windows 7 machine in question has all the latest updates.  Does anyone know what pre-requisites this introduces?  And why they're not part of the standard updates?

My understanding is that cross signing (which is what we do with all our non-driver/LSA binaries) is not actually required unless you want to run on Visa or below...  so Windows 7 should be fine.

By the way on older builds of Windows 7 (without any of the last 6 months of updates) the EV signed dll loads fine...

Comment: Windows 7 x64 needs the "KB3033929" update to be able "accept" the ev signed files.